# SQlite listview results from query case when

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-listview, android-sqlite

Trying to display the sqlite information in Android listview with dual sqlite condition.Query is tested in DB Browser which is giving desired results but i am unable bring the same in Android.

**Real table looks like this:**

[image]
**Sqlite query**

```
SELECT
    number as no,
    outletname as name,

    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" THEN sunday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1S,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" THEN monday  ELSE 0 END) AS WK1M,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" THEN tuesday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1T,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" THEN wednesday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1W,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" THEN thursday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1T,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" THEN saturday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1SA,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK2" THEN sunday ELSE 0 END) AS WK2S,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK2" THEN monday ELSE 0 END) AS WK21M,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" THEN sunday ELSE 0 END) AS WK3S,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" THEN monday ELSE 0 END) AS WK3M,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" THEN tuesday ELSE 0 END) AS WK3T,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" THEN wednesday ELSE 0 END) AS WK3W,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" THEN thursday ELSE 0 END) AS WK3T,
    (CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" THEN saturday ELSE 0 END) AS WK3SA

FROM labels5

     UNION   all
     SELECT "GRAND TOTAL",
    NULL ,


      COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" AND sunday LIKE "%sunday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK1S,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" AND monday LIKE "%monday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK1M,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" AND tuesday LIKE "%tuesday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK1T,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" AND wednesday LIKE "%wednesday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK1W,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" AND thursday LIKE "%thursday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK1T,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" AND saturday LIKE "%saturday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK1SA,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK2" AND sunday LIKE "%sunday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK2S,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK2" AND monday LIKE "%monday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK2M,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK1" AND sunday LIKE "%sunday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK3S,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" AND monday LIKE "%monday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK3M,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" AND tuesday LIKE "%tuesday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK3T,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" AND wednesday LIKE "%wednesday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK3W,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" AND thursday LIKE "%thursday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK3T,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN week = "WEEK3" AND saturday LIKE "%saturday%" THEN 1 END) AS WK3SA

     FROM labels5
```

**Query output:**

[image]

LAYOUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFC7C7C7"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:divider="@drawable/mydivider"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:dividerPadding="22dp"
    android:weightSum="9">



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lvcontainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#FFC7C7C7"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductcompany"
            style="?android:dividerVertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.63"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="number"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductname"
            style="?android:dividerVertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.59"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="name"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="9sp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice1"
            style="?android:dividerVertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="WK1S"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice1"
            style="?android:dividerVertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="WK1M"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="WK1T"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="WK1W"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice4"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="WK1TH"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice5"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="WK2SA"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice122"
            style="?android:dividerVertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="WK2S"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice11"
            style="?android:dividerVertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="WK2M"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="WK2T"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice31"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="WK2W"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice41"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="WK2TH"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice51"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="WK2SA"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice19"
            style="?android:dividerVertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="WK3S"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice13"
            style="?android:dividerVertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="WK3M"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="WK3T"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice33"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="WK3W"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice43"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="WK3TH"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtproductprice53"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="WK3SA"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lvcontainer"
        android:layout_weight="8.72"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:divider="@drawable/separator_line"
        android:dividerHeight="4.0sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:dividerPadding="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:showDividers="beginning|middle|end"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="true"


        ></ListView>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtresulttext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFF55F54"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="italic|bold"></TextView>




    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lvbottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnupload"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#1083f5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="UPLOAD"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**tried with following cursor but no results**

```js
  public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllProducts12() {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> journalList;
        journalList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        //String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM labels5";
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
            String sql1="SELECT number,outletname ("+"CASE WHEN week = WEEK1 THEN sunday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1S," +
                    "(CASE WHEN week = WEEK1 THEN monday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1M,"+
             "(CASE WHEN week = WEEK1 THEN thursday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1TH,"
            +"(CASE WHEN week = WEEK1 THEN tuesday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1T,"
            +"(CASE WHEN week = WEEK1 THEN wednesday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1W,"

                + "FROM" + "labels5 UNION all SELECT GRANDTOTAL"  +"NULL" +

                    "COUNT(CASE WHEN week = WEEK1 AND sunday LIKE sunday THEN 1 END) AS WK1S," +
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN week = WEEK1 AND monday LIKE monday THEN 1 END) AS WK1M,"+
                "COUNT(CASE WHEN week = WEEK1 AND tuesday LIKE tuesday THEN 1 END) AS WK1MT," +
                    "COUNT(CASE WHEN week = WEEK1 AND thursday LIKE thursday THEN 1 END) AS WK1TH,"
                +"COUNT(CASE WHEN week = WEEK1 AND wednesday LIKE wednesday THEN 1 END) AS WK1W,FROM" + "labels5";

        Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery(sql1,null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            do {
                //Id, Company,Name,Price
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("WK1S", cursor.getString(0));
                map.put("WK1M", cursor.getString(1));
                map.put("WK1T", cursor.getString(2));
                map.put("WK1W", cursor.getString(3));
                map.put("WK1TH", cursor.getString(4));
               
                journalList.add(map);
                Log.e("dataofList",cursor.getString(0)+","+cursor.getString(1)+","+cursor.getString(2)+","+cursor.getString(3)+","+cursor.getString(4)+","+cursor.getString(4));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return journalList;
```

error:

Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such function: **GRANDTOTALNULLCOUNT** (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MF4Lq.jpg)): , while compiling: SELECT number,outletname (CASE WHEN week = WEEK1 THEN sunday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1S,(CASE WHEN week = WEEK1 THEN monday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1M,(CASE WHEN week = WEEK1 THEN thursday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1TH,(CASE WHEN week = WEEK1 THEN tuesday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1T,(CASE WHEN week = WEEK1 THEN wednesday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1W,**FROMlabels5 UNION all SELECT GRANDTOTALNULLCOUNT**(CASE WHEN week = WEEK1 AND sunday LIKE sunday THEN 1 END) AS WK1S,COUNT(CASE WHEN week = WEEK1 AND monday LIKE monday THEN 1 END) AS WK1M,COUNT(CASE WHEN week = WEEK1 AND tuesday LIKE tuesday THEN 1 END) AS WK1MT,COUNT(CASE WHEN week = WEEK1 AND thursday LIKE thursday THEN 1 END) AS WK1TH,COUNT(CASE WHEN week = WEEK1 AND wednesday LIKE wednesday THEN 1 END) AS WK1W,**FROMlabels5**
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)

Very unsure about rawquery will support this scenario or not. Would appreciate if anyone can spot the light with suggest cursor query or any would much appreciated

Comment: Friends let me know what i am missing here to share your suggestioin ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you concatenate pieces of sql code, make sure to include spaces or commas between these pieces, and if a column like `"GRAND TOTAL"` contains illegal characters (a space) enclose it in square brackets, or if it is a string literal enclose it in single quotes:

```
String sql1 = "SELECT " +
    "number as no, " +
    "outletname as name, " +
    "(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK1' THEN sunday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1S, " +
    "(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK1' THEN monday  ELSE 0 END) AS WK1M, " +
    "(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK1' THEN tuesday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1T, " +
    "(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK1' THEN wednesday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1W, " +
    "(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK1' THEN thursday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1T, " +
    "(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK1' THEN saturday ELSE 0 END) AS WK1SA, " +
    "(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK2' THEN sunday ELSE 0 END) AS WK2S, " +
    "(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK2' THEN monday ELSE 0 END) AS WK21M, " +
    "(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK3' THEN sunday ELSE 0 END) AS WK3S, " +
    "(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK3' THEN monday ELSE 0 END) AS WK3M, " +
    "(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK3' THEN tuesday ELSE 0 END) AS WK3T, " +
    "(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK3' THEN wednesday ELSE 0 END) AS WK3W, " +
    "(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK3' THEN thursday ELSE 0 END) AS WK3T, " +
    "(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK3' THEN saturday ELSE 0 END) AS WK3SA " +
    "FROM labels5 " +
    "UNION all " +
    "SELECT  " +
    "'GRAND TOTAL', " +
    "NULL , " +
    "COUNT(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK1' AND sunday LIKE '%sunday%' THEN 1 END) AS WK1S, " +
    "COUNT(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK1' AND monday LIKE '%monday%' THEN 1 END) AS WK1M, " +
    "COUNT(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK1' AND tuesday LIKE '%tuesday%' THEN 1 END) AS WK1T, " +
    "COUNT(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK1' AND wednesday LIKE '%wednesday%' THEN 1 END) AS WK1W, " +
    "COUNT(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK1' AND thursday LIKE '%thursday%' THEN 1 END) AS WK1T, " +
    "COUNT(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK1' AND saturday LIKE '%saturday%' THEN 1 END) AS WK1SA, " +
    "COUNT(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK2' AND sunday LIKE '%sunday%' THEN 1 END) AS WK2S, " +
    "COUNT(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK2' AND monday LIKE '%monday%' THEN 1 END) AS WK2M, " +
    "COUNT(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK1' AND sunday LIKE '%sunday%' THEN 1 END) AS WK3S, " +
    "COUNT(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK3' AND monday LIKE '%monday%' THEN 1 END) AS WK3M, " +
    "COUNT(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK3' AND tuesday LIKE '%tuesday%' THEN 1 END) AS WK3T, " +
    "COUNT(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK3' AND wednesday LIKE '%wednesday%' THEN 1 END) AS WK3W, " +
    "COUNT(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK3' AND thursday LIKE '%thursday%' THEN 1 END) AS WK3T, " +
    "COUNT(CASE WHEN week = 'WEEK3' AND saturday LIKE '%saturday%' THEN 1 END) AS WK3SA " +
    "FROM labels5";
```

Comment: following error "<result column> expected for,'FROM'

Comment: i have given my table screenshot inwhich i am bringing these information

Answer (score 0):

You may have missed spaces between these columns:
"labels5 UNION all SELECT GRANDTOTAL"  +"NULL" + "COUNT ...
try to change it to:
"labels5 UNION all SELECT GRANDTOTAL "  +"NULL" + " COUNT ...